# Itachiyama Academy game and team in haikyuu

Tags: haikyuu

From the first appearance, Sakusa is very hyped and especially Itachiyama Academy. They are supposed to one of the best schools who won nationals without even playing 5 sets. But I can't find much information about them. Not about how they play or list of players.

Is there any filler or some side novel in which we can find information about them?